# ¿Cómo hacer una consulta con Linq (C#) para filtrar datos por coincidencias?

Tags: c#, linq, sql

Estoy haciendo un proyecto para una asignatura de la universidad y me pidieron hacer una API REST para una entidad bancaria. Estoy utilizando EntityFramework v5.0.

En la capa de negocio tengo la clase del cliente con los siguientes métodos.

```
using BancoChiloeDataAccess;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

public class Cliente
    {
        public int ClienteId { get; set; }
        public string Nombre { get; set; }
        public string Apellido { get; set; }
        public int Telefono { get; set; }

        BancoChiloeEntities BD = new BancoChiloeEntities();

        public Cliente(int id)
        {
            this.ClienteId = id;
        }

        public Cliente(int id, string nombre, string apellido, int telefono)
        {
            this.ClienteId = id;
            this.Nombre = nombre;
            this.Apellido = apellido;
            this.Telefono = telefono;
        }

        public List<Cliente> selectAll()
        {
            return BD.CLIENTE.Select(c => new Cliente() {
                ClienteId = (int)c.CLIENTE_ID,
                Nombre = c.CLIENTE_NOMBRE,
                Apellido = c.CLIENTE_APELLIDO,
                Telefono = (int)c.CLIENTE_TELEFONO
            }).ToList();
        }

        public bool insertRow()
        {
            try
            {
                BD.SP_CREAR_CLIENTE(this.Nombre, this.Apellido, this.Telefono);
                return true;
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                throw new Exception("Error en la ejecución de la consulta.");
            }
        }

        public bool updateRow()
        {
            try
            {
                BD.SP_ACTUALIZAR_CLIENTE(this.ClienteId, this.Nombre, this.Apellido, this.Telefono.ToString());
                return true;
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                throw new Exception("Error en la ejecución de la consulta.");
            }
        }

        public bool deleteRow()
        {
            try
            {
                BD.SP_ELIMINAR_CLIENTE(this.ClienteId);
                return true;
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                throw new Exception("Error en la ejecución de la consulta.");
            }
        }

    }
```

Me piden crear un método para buscar clientes por el nombre pero, me pide filtrar los datos por coincidencia, es decir, si yo en el parámetro del nombre ingreso ad, que me devuelva los usuarios que coinciden que ese término, en este caso admin, administrador, adm, y cualquier usuario que coincida con el termino de la búsqueda.

No recuerdo muy bien como hacer esto con LINQ y lo último que me falta para completar el proyecto.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para buscar una coincidencia por una parte de la cadena se usa el método `Contains()`, opcionalmente se le puede especificar que ignore las mayúsculas con `StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase`.

```
List<string> nombres = new List<string>(){"Admin","Administrador", "Adm"};

var filtro = nombres.Where(nombre => nombre.Contains("Ad",StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase));

foreach(var nombre in filtro){
    Console.WriteLine(nombre);
}
```

Comment: Esta es la solución, me has ayudado mucho. Gracias.